# Automatic matching of right column

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, having the following two dataframes:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:8, value = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(randomColumnName = c(100L, 2L, 3L, 40L, 5L, 6L, 73L, 8L), OtherRandomColumn =    structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "'test'", class = "factor"), value = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

print(df1)

  id value
1  1   100
2  2   100
3  3   100
4  4   100
5  5   100
6  6   100
7  7   100
8  8   100

print(df2)

  randomColumnName OtherRandomColumn value
1              100            'test'   100
2                2            'test'   100
3                3            'test'   100
4               40            'test'   100
5                5            'test'   100
6                6            'test'   100
7               73            'test'   100
8                8            'test'   100
```

Dataframe 1 has a unique id column called 'id'. I know that df2 also has a column which contains **some but not all** id's. Upfront, I do not know the column name of the corresponding column in dataframe 2.

**Question**:

Is there any handy function or mechanism to check the first few entries (e.g. 50) of each column in df2, compare them to the id column of df, and return the column name of df2 that is most likely to match the ID column?

In this case, it should return that column 'randomColumnName' is the most likely column to match df1's ID column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following using data.table. It outputs a data.table (hitmat) depicting the fraction of entries in each column of df2 which matches an id from df1. As you can see, randomColumnName has a 5/8 (62.5%) 'match' fraction vis-a-vis df1$id.

What the code does in practise is counting the number of matches to df1$id across unique values of each column in df2. Note that this solution assumes that appropriate matching entries in df2 are unique, as you stated that they are in df1. If a correct match can appear several times in df2, simply remove unique() in the lapply statement.

```
df1 = data.table(df1)
df2 = data.table(df2)

ids = df1$id # Get IDS
cols = colnames(df2) # Source appropriate subset for df2

hitmat = df2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(unique(x) %in% ids)/length(x)), .SDcols = cols]

> hitmat
   randomColumnName OtherRandomColumn value
1:            0.625                 0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to loop over df2 and check each column against `df1$id`. The column with the biggest sum is your column to merge on. Note that the output of that is a named vector so you can use either the name or its index.

```
i1 <- which.max(sapply(df2, function(i) sum(df1$id == i)))
names(i1)
#[1] "randomColumnName"
i1
#randomColumnName 
#               1
```

Comment: This will fail if the values in different rows.

Comment: @A.Suliman True. We could put `%in%` or `match` but If another column has integers the same with `id` it will again fail. There are lot of corner cases here. Maybe there are duplicates, maybe...etc, etc . OP is not clear and based on their description, the id and other column will be equal one-by-one